# git rev-parse --verify says "fatal: Needed a single revision"

Tags: git

Consider this test script.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

rm -rf origin clone
git init origin
cd origin
echo foo > file
git add -A
git commit -m "initial commit"
git branch foo

cd ..
git clone origin clone
cd clone
git rev-parse --verify foo
```

We create an `origin` repo, create a branch named `foo`, clone the repo, and in the clone, we attempt to validate that the name `foo` is a valid object with `git rev-parse --verify foo`.

But when I run this, it says, "fatal: Needed a single revision" which doesn't make any sense to me.

I guess it's trying to tell me that `foo` isn't a branch name, that only `origin/foo` exists? But it obviously works when I `git checkout foo`.

Overall, what I'm trying to do is verify in advance that `git checkout foo` will work, without actually running `git checkout foo`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct: branch `foo` does not exist in the clone.

The clone process normally copies all the branches—more precisely, references of the form `refs/heads/*`—to remote-tracking branches, references of the form `refs/remotes/<remote>/*`.  (The name of the remote is whatever you specify with `-o`, or `origin` if you don't specify anything.)

After the clone completes, `git clone` does a `git checkout` of the branch you specify with `-b`.  If you don't specify something, it uses what it can see for `HEAD` to decide what to `git checkout`; most often, it just winds up doing `git checkout master`.

It's that last `git checkout master` step that actually creates the local branch `master`, due to this bit from the `git checkout` documentation:

> If *branch* is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in
>    exactly one remote (call it *remote*) with a matching name, treat
>    as equivalent to
>     `$ git checkout -b branch --track remote/branch`

So if you're sure you've just `git clone`d so that there is only one remote, and you know the name of the remote is `origin`, you can simply do a `git rev-parse --verify origin/foo` to find out if that remote-tracking branch exists.  (Modify as needed for a differently-named remote; and/or, use `git remote` to get a list of all possible remotes, then loop over all remotes to find out if there's exactly one branch named `foo`, if needed.)

I'm not sure if this process is totally foolproof if some remote has weirdly-valued `fetch =` lines, e.g., if remote `origin` fetches into remote-tracking branches named `refs/remotes/weird/master` instead of `refs/remotes/origin/master`, it's possible that `git checkout` will be OK with this, but if you check for `origin/master` you won't find it.  (On the other hand, weirdly-valued `fetch =` lines will confuse other bits of git, including some code I was looking at in `git pull` this morning.)